# which client receives the message from a queue

Tags: jms, message-queue, consumer

if i have one messagequeue and multiple standalone programs which try to receive messages from this queue via

```
sess.receive();
```

which clientprogram will actually receive the message? how is this decided?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things being equal, any of the receivers could receive the message (but only one of them).
Architecturaly speaking, you should not care which receiver gets the message.
If you have different message handling in the receivers, you should consider using selectors or different queues.